# How to print pandas types without 'dtype'?

Tags: python, pandas

When I write

`print(set(df_.dtypes))`

I'm getting:

`{dtype('int64'), dtype('float64')}`

Is it possible to get the result like:

`int64, float64` or `[int64, float64]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can

```
set(df.dtypes.map(lambda x : x.name))
Out[379]: {'float64', 'int64', 'object'}
```

Comment: Thank you! I modified your code to a bit faster version `set([x.name for x in df_.dtypes])`

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
str(df_.dtypes).split()[1::2][:-1]
```

Explanations:

- `df_.dtypes` : get the types of each columns
- `str(df_.dtypes)`: convert the previous results to string
- `.split()` : split the string by space
- `[1::2]` : select every 2 elements of the list (starting at 1)
- `[:-1]` : remove the last element of the list (useless here)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work properly. `str(df_.dtypes).split()[1::2]` returns at some point column names next to the types: `...'int64', 'int64', 'float64', 'D1747', 'D1748', 'D1749'...` There are 2k columns in my dataframe.

Comment: Quite sure there some space in your columns names. The Yenyoben solution is for sure better. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You might use **df.dtypes**

```
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    df['A']=['a','b','c']
    df['B']=[1,2,3]
    df['C']=[1.3,4.6,0.01]
    print(df.dtypes)
```

**output:**
A     object 
B      int64
C    float64
dtype: object

[image: data type of the column]